# Looking for a Team (A Question about Blender Community)

Tags: workflow

This is a question about the Blender community itself.

We have a list of resources ([Resources for Blender](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15355/resources-for-blender)) of things like sounds, models, and addons, but the one for community organizations has just been added, and may not be of much use for a while. I want to recruit a team for my first animation, *Ignite Cascade*. It is thirty minutes long.

Is this the right place to ask this question (that is, should it be moved to meta?) Is this the wrong place to ask for a team to be assembled?

Comment: Try the forum on www.blenderartists.org  There are forums for paid and volunteer work. Other resource is https://www.blendernetwork.org/

Comment: Thirty minutes long animation? :O I don't want to to discourage you but you should first listen to this: http://www.blenderguru.com/podcasts/podcast-why-i-refuse-all-community-projects/
If you're looking for volunteers for your proyect, you should visit: http://blenderartists.org/forum/forumdisplay.php?53-Volunteer-Work
Good luck!

Comment: Umm... this is a nonprofit freelance assignment with a total budget of zero U.S. dollars zero cents, meaning I really have to find people who are willing to work for free.

Comment: It's really not about Blender as defined by the scope of the  help center.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about a job/volunteer project, and not about using blender as defined in the [help center](http://blender.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). You might try over on [blenderartists](http://blenderartists.org/forum/forumdisplay.php?53-Volunteer-Work)

Comment: Ah, thanks, that's what I wanted to know: if there was a place to ask for a team.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you go to the [user community](http://www.blender.org/support/user-community/) page on the Blender website, you will find a number of sites on line where there are blender users participating in forums, including a facebook page, where you might recruit members for your development team.

Good luck. A 30 minute animation is quite an undertaking.